# How to prevent duplicate records

Tags: sql

How to prevent duplicate records in time of insertion?   need a solution other than setting unique

Comment: What sort of duplicate insertion is occuring?  A single SQL insert is resulting in duplicate entities?  Two competing threads are both inserting identical records?  Users are hitting an "insert" button more than once?

Comment: So you want uniqueness without uniqueness? How does that add up? Please describe what you have, what you want, what you've already tried and what problems you had with this more accurately. Code snippets welcome. Consider to provide DDL along with test data as well.

Comment: no i want to avoid inserting duplicate records..or i want to check each and every record and field it is exist or not

Comment: I want to know is it done without adding unique..thats all

Comment: What do you mean by "adding unique"? Constraint? Index? You could write a trigger that checks for uniqueness. But why don't you want the standard way, the DBMS provides? It sure is faster and safer than anything you tinker atop.

Comment: Which rdbms? Some have unique keys, some have triggers, some have upsert...

Comment: Creating a unique constraint is the **only** sensible solution.

Comment: what about using ' on duplicate key update' ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible although quite lengthy as compare to altering column to unique.
You can do this, Insert all your data to a temporary table and compare it with destination table.
and filter out all duplicate records

```
CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE (ID INT);
INSERT INTO YOURTABLE VALUES (10),(20),(30),(40),(50),(60);


CREATE TABLE TEMP (ID INT);
INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES (10),(20),(80),(90),(100),(110);


INSERT INTO YOURTABLE
  SELECT T.* FROM YOURTABLE Y RIGHT OUTER JOIN TEMP T ON T.ID = Y.ID 
  WHERE Y.ID IS NULL

 DELETE FROM TEMP;
```